# When should we use @InjectMocks?

Tags: testing, junit, mockito

I have read through a lot of discussion about @Mock & @InjectMocks and still could not find what are the suitable or necessary cases to use @InjectMocks. In fact, I am not sure about what would happen when we use @InjectMocks.

Consider the following example,

```
public class User {
  private String user_name;
  private int user_id;
  public User(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
  }
  public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
  }
  public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
  }
  public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
  }
  public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
  }     
}

public interface UserDao {
  public List<User> getUserList();
}

public class UserService {
  private UserDao userDao;  
  public UserDao getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
  }
  public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
  }
  public List<User> getUserList() {
    return userDao.getUserList();
  }
}
```

This is my test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {  
  private UserService service = new UserService();
  @Mock
  private UserDao dao;

  @Test
  public void testGetUserList() {

    service.setUserDao(dao);

    // mock the return value of the mock object
    List<User> mockResult = Arrays.asList(new User(101),new User(102),new User(103));       
    when(dao.getUserList()).thenReturn(mockResult);

    // check return value is same as mocked value
    assertEquals(service.getUserList(),mockResult);

    // verify the getUserList() function is called
    verify(dao).getUserList();  
  }
}
```

The test run successfully with no errors.
Consider another approach using @InjectMock annotation.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {  

  @InjectMocks
  private UserService service;
  @Mock
  private UserDao dao;

  @Test
  public void testGetUserList() {

    service.setUserDao(dao);

    // mock the return value of the mock object
    List<User> mockResult = Arrays.asList(new User(101),new User(102),new User(103));       
    when(dao.getUserList()).thenReturn(mockResult);

    // check return value is same as mocked value
    assertEquals(service.getUserList(),mockResult);

    // verify the getUserList() function is called
    verify(dao).getUserList();  
  }
}
```

This works equally well. So, which way is better? Any best practice? 
Btw, I am using Junit 4.8.1 and Mockito 1.9.5

Comment: And a hint: *please teach me* is exactly **not** what this site is about. Mind your wording the next time!

Comment: Thanks for the timely accept. Is there anything else I could do to make my answer upvote-worthy in your eyes, too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your actual question can't be answered without you providing further code (the code you are showing does not explain the results you claim to observe).

Regarding the underlying question: you probably *should not* use @InjectMocks; one of its core problems is: if injecting fails, Mockito does **not** report an error to you.

In other words: you have passing unit tests, and some internal detail about a field changes ... and your unit tests break; but you have no idea why ... because the mocking framework doesn't tell you that the "initial" step of pushing a mock into the class under test is all of a sudden failing. See [here](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) for further reading.

But to be clear here: in the end, this almost a pure *style* question. People used to @InjectMocks will love it; other people do object it. Meaning: there is no clear evidence whether you **should** use this concept. Instead: you study the concept, you understand the concept, and then you (and the team working with you) make a conscious decision whether you **want** to use this annotation, or not.

Edit: I think I get your problem now. The idea of @InjectMocks is to **inject** a mocked object **into** some **object under test**.

But: you are doing that **manually** in both cases:

```
 service.setUserDao(dao);
```

Meaning: if *injecting* works correctly (and there isn't a problem that isn't reported by Mockito) then your example that uses that annotation should **also** work when you remove that one line. Whereas the testcase that doesn't have @InjectMocks should **fail** without that line!

In other words: your testcases are both passing because your code does a "manual inject"!

Comment: I agree this is kind of style or personal taste. I am now studying the concept and still could not get it. So, I am struggling whether I should use it or not to use it.

Comment: Suggestion: rework your question and create a real  [mcve] so we can understand why your code is working in both cases. Maybe that helps you to decide whether that annotation adds value for you.

Comment: I have updated my example which is more close to my current work. Yet, I am not sure what @InjectMocks actually does. I only need a mock object  and isolate the dependency of the class under test. I expect the class under test behaves exactly what it does. So, I would prefer using a raw method (new an instance of it).

Comment: Wow!! I tried to remove the line service.setUserDao(dao); and the test passes too! My next question is how come mockito know my @mock refer to a particular data member of the class under test? What if the class under test has two private data member of the same class (e.g. two UserDao )?

Comment: That would be another question. But probably one that is easily answered by reading Mockito documentation. I thing the library simply uses various heuristics to "identify" the best "match".

Answer (score 1):

> When should we use `@InjectMocks`?

IHMO : we should not use it.
That favors so many design issues that I would like to add my POV on the question.

[Here is relevant information from the javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) (emphasis is not mine) :

> Mark a field on which injection should be performed.
>
> - Allows shorthand mock and spy injection.
> - Minimizes repetitive mock and spy injection.
>
> Mockito will try to inject mocks only either by constructor injection,
>   setter injection, or property injection in order and as described
>   below. If any of the following strategy fail, then Mockito **won't
>   report failure**; i.e. you will have to provide dependencies yourself.
>   ...
>    Mockito is not an dependency injection framework,

In two words :

Advantage : you write less code to setup your mock dependencies.
Drawback : no failure if some mocks were not be set in the object under test.

IHMO the advantage hides also another drawback still more serious.

**About the advantage  :**
Mockito uses constructor/setter/reflection to set the mocks in the object under test.  The problem is that it is up to you to decide the way to set your fields : mockito will try one after the other way.

The setter way is often very verbose and provides mutability of the dependencies. So developers don't use it frequently.  It makes sense.
The constructor way to set the bean dependencies requires to keep a good design with a decent number of dependencies : not more than 4 or 5 in general.
It demands strong design exigencies.
At last, the reflection way is the most easy : few code to write and no mutability of the dependencies.
The reflection way being the simplest from the lambda developer PVO, I saw many teams not aware of the consequences of reflection to specify dependencies and abuse of the reflection way in their Mockito tests but also in their design since finally `InjectMocks` allows to cope with it in a someway.
You may consider it fine to not finish with a class that declares 30 setters as dependencies or a constructor with 30 arguments but that has also a strong drawback : it favors bad smells such as dependency field hiding and declaration of many dependencies in as field instances of the class. As a result your class is complex, bloat, hard to read, hard to test and error prone to maintain.

The real thing is that in the very most of cases, the right solution is the constructor injection that promotes decent class responsibility and so good maintainability and testability of that.

**About the drawback :**
Mock injection doesn't work as the dependency injection of IOCs.
The javadoc states itself :

> Mockito is not an dependency injection framework,

IOC and DI framework are able and by default consider dependencies as required.  So any missing dependency will provoke a [fast-fail error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) at the startup.
It prevents so many headaches and makes you win a precious time.
While Mockito injection will silently ignore the mocks that were not managed to be injected.   It is so up to you to guess the error cause.
Finding the issue cause is sometimes complex because you don't have any clue from Mockito and that all is done by reflection by Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

Using @InjectMocks injects the mocked objects as dependencies to the created object(The object marked by @InjectMocks). Creating an object using constructor will defy the purpose since the mocked objects are not injected and hence all the external calls from SUT takes place on concrete objects.Try to avoid creating SUT object by constructor call.

Comment: If the mocked object is not injected by using constructor call, how come my mock object return value is working (by when().thenReturn() clause)?

Comment: Perhaps your concrete implementation too returns the same value.

Comment: @sudheersingh `@InjectMocks` annotation won't create an object. In will just inject the mocks into the object.